# How do I install Ubuntu onto a laptop with a 32GB SSD drive a 500GB hard drive? I want to take advantage of the quick boot option

Tags: hp, ssd

Some people have suggested symlinking, but I have no idea how to accomplish that (despite Googling for quite a while).

Someone recommended using these steps: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbYhk.jpg

Specs: 14" HP 4t-1000 SleekBook 4GB RAM 500GB Hard Drive 32GB SSD

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't.  The intel fakeraid caching option is not supported in Linux.  If you want to install Ubuntu, you will have to do so either on a non cached volume of the hd, or on the ssd, and not have it cache the hd.

Comment: So, do you mean I should install it on the HD and leave the SSD alone?

Answer (score 1):

Assumption: I guess that you don't have hybrid drive.

Then, you should normally see more partitions and are free to choosing how it will be organized. I would recommend installing the OS this way:

- root partition ("/") on SSD
- boot partition ("/boot") on SSD

  - If not working, try having the /boot on your HDD
- for other huge data (like "/home") => HDD
- consider having the "/var", "/tmp" also on your SDD
- SWAP: if you're using hibernation, place it on SSD...otherwise, try buying more RAM and don't use swap at all